# GPU not used when running XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, xgboost

I'm quite new in ML world, for my project done with XGBoost model I tried to use my GPU for GridSearch and parameter tuning. Unfortunatelly I have feeling that my GPU is not used, as info displayed about runtime of each fold is ~ 0,1 sec on CPU and ~ 0,9 sec when using 'gpu_hist' parameter.

I installed CUDA toolkit, so it's not the issue.

This is what happens when passing 'gpu_hist' tree method parameter:
[gpu_hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNlae.png)

This is what happens without it:
[without gpu parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sK6c.png)

Do you have any idea how I can enable GPU to work?
Can this problem be due to integrated graphic in my CPU?

I face same problem using jupyter notebook and pycharm.

My CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7900x
My GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 3070

Thank you in advance!

I tried running pytorch command

```
import torch
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()

if use_cuda:
    print('__CUDNN VERSION:', torch.backends.cudnn.version())
    print('__Number CUDA Devices:', torch.cuda.device_count())
    print('__CUDA Device Name:',torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
    print('__CUDA Device Total Memory [GB]:',torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9)
```

to see if my GPU is recognized but everything seems ok, since I get:

__CUDNN VERSION: 8700

__Number CUDA Devices: 1

__CUDA Device Name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070

__CUDA Device Total Memory [GB]: 8.589410304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while but maybe a reply is warranted since I spent some time figuring this out. Try this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import xgboost as xgb

# Fetch dataset using sklearn
data = fetch_california_housing()
X = data.data
y = data.target

num_round = 1000

param = {
    "eta": 0.05,
    "max_depth": 10,
    "tree_method": "hist",
    "device": "cpu",  # switch between "cpu" and "GPU" 
    "nthread": 24,  # increase this to increase CPU threads
    "seed": 42
}

# GPU accelerated or CPU multicore training
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y, feature_names=data.feature_names)
model = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
```

On 24 threads I am getting:
`CPU times: user 1min 9s, sys: 43.7 ms, total: 1min 9s. Wall time: 2.95 s`

On 32 threads I am getting:
`CPU times: user 1min 40s, sys: 33.8 ms, total: 1min 40s Wall time: 3.19 s`

With a GPU I am getting:
`CPU times: user 6.47 s, sys: 9.98 ms, total: 6.48 s Wall time: 5.96 s`

XGBoost does not scale too well with increasing parallelism. Sending to a GPU can actually increase training time for XGBoost

On the other hand, if you need to compute feature importance with SHAP

```
import shap    
model.set_param({"device": "gpu"}) # "cpu" or "gpu"
shap_values = model.predict(dtrain, pred_contribs=True)
```

On 32 threads I am getting:
`CPU times: user 43min 43s, sys: 54.2 ms, total: 43min 43s Wall time: 1min 23s`

With a GPU I am getting:
`CPU times: user 3.06 s, sys: 28 ms, total: 3.09 s Wall time: 3.09 s`

So SHAP computation is highly accelerated on a GPU.

There are more examples of XGBoost on CPU vs. GPU [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/explain-your-machine-learning-model-predictions-with-gpu-accelerated-shap/)
The GPUTreeShap paper is [here](https://peerj.com/articles/cs-880/#)

This is on NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090/AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core

Comment: Hey, thank you for answer and you time spent on this topic! It is true that XGBoost is not doing extremely better on GPU with increased parallelism. In meantime I changed my GPU for RTX 4090 and boy I can tell the difference when performing calculations with tensor LSTM (CPU vs GPU). Eventually I figured out, that propably my type of data is not the best for measuring times of calculations (thousands of rows, only 2 features). Thank you for article from NVIDIA, glad that someone tested SHAP in that mater :)