# How can I reduce processing time with xgboost by utilizing my GPU?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/xgboost-in-python) on data camp and one thing they mentioned was utilizing your GPU for faster processing times. They even go as far to say it is "blazing fast".

I, however, am seeing the opposite results. For the code block below, with 10k boosts, I am see ~30 seconds with `"hist"` passed in my `params` vs just over a minute with `"gpu_hist"` passed with my `params`.

Usage on my GPU caps out at 40% when using `"gpu_hist"` and 100% on all 24 logical cores when using `"hist"`

```py
params = {"objective": "reg:squarederror", "tree_method": "gpu_hist", "subsample": 0.8,
    "colsample_bytree": 0.8}

evals = [(dtrain_reg, "train"),(dtest_reg, "validation")]

n = 10000


model = xgb.train(
   params=params,
   dtrain=dtrain_reg,
   num_boost_round=n,
   evals=evals,
   verbose_eval=50,
)
```

I'm trying to run this in VSCode in a jupyter notebook.

- I've installed the CUDA toolkit and cuDNN
- I've checked that they are added to the path
- I've ensured that I installed the correct version of xgboost to utilize the gpu.
- the data set is 53k rows with 10 columns, so I do not believe the dataset is too small
- I've confirmed compatibility (using an RTX 2060)

I've asked chatGPT, searched online, even asked a mentor in the course I'm taking but have not been able to diagnose why it's taking so much longer with "gpu_hist" vs just "hist".

There is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76827589/gpu-not-used-when-running-xgboost) here in Stack Overflow from 4 months ago that has zero responses.

Comment: The GPU is being used, but a common misconception is that it always improves performance, and that is not true, as you saw it can be slower depending on the workload.

Comment: GPUs differ massively in performance between models, and without knowing your CPU, if it has 12 cores and 24 threads, is most probably just plain faster than your 2060 for xgboost. GPU won't always be better. In addition, it might be that if your dataset is larger than the VRAM available to your GPU, it might drastically slow it's performance (not sure about xgboost specifics).
Also, the 2060 has only 1,920 CUDA cores (compared to 16000 for the 4090 for example). It's not such a good GPU for training.

Comment: @CrispyHoliday thanks for the response - I think I was thrown off by the articles wording saying that it would be "blazing fast" so when it was twice as long I thought something was wrong. As for my CPU it's a 3900X

Comment: Is it possible to squeeze more out of my GPU? It is capping at 40% usage while my CPU is at 100%

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but maybe a reply is warranted since I spent some time figuring this out. Try this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import xgboost as xgb

# Fetch dataset using sklearn
data = fetch_california_housing()
X = data.data
y = data.target

num_round = 1000

param = {
    "eta": 0.05,
    "max_depth": 10,
    "tree_method": "hist",
    "device": "cpu",  # switch between "cpu" and "GPU" 
    "nthread": 24,  # increase this to increase CPU threads
    "seed": 42
}

# GPU accelerated or CPU multicore training
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y, feature_names=data.feature_names)
model = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
```

On 24 threads I am getting:
`CPU times: user 1min 9s, sys: 43.7 ms, total: 1min 9s. Wall time: 2.95 s`

On 32 threads I am getting:
`CPU times: user 1min 40s, sys: 33.8 ms, total: 1min 40s Wall time: 3.19 s`

With a GPU I am getting:
`CPU times: user 6.47 s, sys: 9.98 ms, total: 6.48 s Wall time: 5.96 s`

XGBoost does not scale too well with increasing parallelism. Sending to a GPU can actually increase training time for XGBoost

On the other hand, if you need to compute feature importance with SHAP

```
import shap    
model.set_param({"device": "gpu"}) # "cpu" or "GPU"
shap_values = model.predict(dtrain, pred_contribs=True)
```

On 32 threads I am getting:
`CPU times: user 43min 43s, sys: 54.2 ms, total: 43min 43s Wall time: 1min 23s`

With a GPU I am getting:
`CPU times: user 3.06 s, sys: 28 ms, total: 3.09 s Wall time: 3.09 s`

So SHAP computation is highly accelerated on a GPU.

There are more examples of XGBoost on CPU vs. GPU [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/explain-your-machine-learning-model-predictions-with-gpu-accelerated-shap/)
The GPUTreeShap paper is [here](https://peerj.com/articles/cs-880/#)

This is on NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090/AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core